# Using two replaces in Python

Tags: python, replace

I'm new to Python and I realized I can't concatenate `replace` like in JavaScript:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import re
import string

for filename in os.listdir("."):
  if filename.endswith(".png"):
    new_filename = string.replace(filename, "2x", "@3x").replace(filename, "-lanczos3", "")

    os.rename(filename, new_filename)
```

I get this error:

```
File "hello.py", line 8, in <module>
    new_filename = string.replace(filename, "2x", "@3x").replace(filename, "-lanczos3", "")
TypeError: an integer is required
```

What's the Python way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) (a method) on the return value of [`string.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) (a function returning a `str` object).

Just use the methods:

```
new_filename = filename.replace("2x", "@3x").replace("-lanczos3", "")
```

Your error stems from the third argument to `str.replace()` which must be an integer limiting the number of replacements. You basically did this:

```
'somestring'.replace(thingto_replace, "-lanczos3", "")
```

where the `""` argument is not an integer number.

You *could* do the same thing with `string.replace()`, but then you'd have to pass the result of one call in as the first argument of the other call:

```
new_filename = string.replace(string.replace(filename, "2x", "@3x"), "-lanczos3", "")
```

You *don't* want to do this howewer, as the `string` functions have been deprecated; see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#deprecated-string-functions):

> The following list of functions are also defined as methods of string and Unicode objects; see section String Methods for more information on those. You should consider these functions as deprecated, although they will not be removed until Python 3.

Any of the functions in that section have equivalent methods directly available on the `str` type itself.

Answer (score 4):

I'm also quite new to python, but my guess would be to change this line:

```
new_filename = string.replace(filename, "2x", "@3x").(filename, "-lanczos3", "")
```

into:

```
new_filename = filename.replace("2x", "@3x").replace("-lanczos3", "")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
filename.replace("2x", "@3x").replace("-lanczos3", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

call `replace` on `filename`. Like this:

```
filename = "abcd"
filename.replace("a", "b").replace("c", "d")
```

This returns

```
'bbdd'
```